# Linear Feedback Shift Register: Tapping 1 bit

Tags: xor, lfsr

In an xor lfsr, the bit to be shifted in is the xor of all the tapped bits. But if you tap only 1 bit, does that mean 0 is always the bit that is shifted in, since the 1 bit that is tapped is xor'ed with itself?

Thanks

Comment: No - because it's not xor'ed with itself.  (Though of course, no real LFSR would consist of a single tap.)

Comment: Then what is the bit that's shifted in, if you only have 1 tap?

Comment: As I said, you don't have one tap in any realistic scenario.  But if you do, then it's just the value of the tapped bit.